# NSOperationQueue that pauses between operations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I want to make an NSOperationQueue that pauses a certain length of time between operations. It is hitting a remote server and I want to make sure that I don't overload it with too many operations all at once. I already have set maxConcurrentOperations to 1, so that only one will run at a time.

Comment: How about interleaving the queue with operations that do nothing but wait for N seconds?

Comment: Will that kill battery life? I plan to run this NSOperationQueue, not on the main thread - will this affect it?

Comment: putting a thread to sleep won't affect battery life.  You can't ensure your server won't be overloaded via this method, unless you limit distribution of your client application.  The server will ultimately be asked to resolve the same net number of queries, making your end users wait seems punitive.

Comment: What's the use of the delay when your operations are already executed in serial?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post which describes adding a sleep operation between your operations:
[iPhone - a delay between operations in the queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428516/iphone-a-delay-between-operations-in-the-queue)